# Вывести только те поля, у которых в присоединённой таблице количество строк больше 0

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT DISTINCT parent.`EMAIL` AS ADDRESS,
                            3 AS MESSAGE_TEMPLATE_ID,
                            0 AS STATUS, 
                            parent.ID AS MEMBER_ID,
            count(schedules.ID) as schedules_count
                            FROM members as student
              LEFT JOIN members as `parent` on `parent`.`ID` = student.PARENT_ID
              LEFT JOIN members_classes on student.ID = members_classes.MEMBER_ID
              LEFT JOIN schedules on schedules.CLASS_ID = members_classes.CLASS_ID AND schedules.START > '2016-10-11 12:00:00'
                            WHERE parent.LOGIN_GROUP IN ('client')
                  AND parent.STATUS = 1
            GROUP BY schedules.ID
```

Есть такой запрос, как мне сделать что бы выводились только те строки где count(schedules.ID) больше 0?

Comment: добавить в WHERE  AND schedules_count>0 пробовали?

Comment: Не подходит, ведь WHERE  срабатывает раньше чем присоединяется таблица

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Использовать `HAVING` нужно:

```
SELECT DISTINCT parent.`EMAIL` AS ADDRESS,
                            3 AS MESSAGE_TEMPLATE_ID,
                            0 AS STATUS, 
                            parent.ID AS MEMBER_ID,
            count(schedules.ID) as schedules_count
                            FROM members as student
              LEFT JOIN members as `parent` on `parent`.`ID` = student.PARENT_ID
              LEFT JOIN members_classes on student.ID = members_classes.MEMBER_ID
              LEFT JOIN schedules on schedules.CLASS_ID = members_classes.CLASS_ID AND schedules.START > '2016-10-11 12:00:00'
                            WHERE parent.LOGIN_GROUP IN ('client')
                  AND parent.STATUS = 1
            GROUP BY schedules.ID
            HAVING schedules_count > 0;
```